# If you read it immediately after reloading, you will get an error "Cannot read property'image' of null"

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

## What I want to come true

I want the page to be displayed correctly from the beginning.
When I first access the page after reloading, I get the error  `Cannot read property'image' of null`.
However, After accessing the page several times, the correct page will be displayed.
No error occurs.
Please tell me the correct way to deal with this problem

## Code

List screen

```js
<template>
  <v-container class="back">
    <div
      v-if="registeredBooks.length === 0"
      class="text-center"
    >
      <p class="pa-13">
       No Book
      </p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <v-row class="ma-3">
        <v-col
          v-for="(book, index) in registeredBooks"
          :key="index"
          cols="12"
          class="ma-1"
        >
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          <v-card
            :to="`/book/${book.id}`" // Error in access immediately after reloading
            hover
            class="ma-1"
          >
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            <v-row>
              <v-col class="ml-2">
                <img :src="book.image">
              </v-col>
              <div
                class="ma-3 mt-13"
                align="end"
              >
                <v-card-title>{{ book.title }}</v-card-title>
                <v-card-subtitle>{{ book.author }}</v-card-subtitle>
              </div>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>

        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import * as url from '@/store/constants/url'
export default {

  // Get registeredBook array
  computed: {
    registeredBooks () {
      return this.$store.state.book.registeredBook
    }
  },

  // Get book info
  mounted () {
    this.$axios.$get(url.POST_API + 'posts')
      .then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit('book/registeredBook', response)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Details screen**
`/_id.vue`

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div
      class="teal lighten-1 background pa-10"
    >
      <div v-if="selectedRegisteredBook === 'OK'">
        <AlertSuccess />
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="selectedRegisteredBook === 'ERROR'">
        <AlertError />
      </div>
      <v-sheet
        width="1100px"
        class="mx-auto pa-5 rounded-xl"
        color="grey lighten-5"
        min-height="500px"
      >

        // Show selected data
        <RegisteredBookEdit />
      </v-sheet>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import * as url from '@/store/constants/url'
export default {
  computed: {
    selectedRegisteredBook () {
      return this.$store.state.book.selectedRegisteredBook
    }
  },
  // 選択した本を表示
  mounted () {
    this.$axios.$get(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + this.$route.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit('book/selectedBook', response.post)
        this.$store.commit('todos/regissterdListAdd', response.content)
        console.log(this.$store.state.book.selectedBook)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row style="text-align:center;">
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      <v-col cols="6" class="pa-5">
        <img :src="selectedBook.image"> Cannot read property 'image' of null ??
      </v-col>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      <v-col cols="4" class="pa-5">
        <v-card-title>{{ selectedBook.title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle class="pa-3">
          {{ selectedBook.author }}
        </v-card-subtitle>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <!-- text -->
    <BookPostText />
    <v-divider
      class="ma-7"
    />
    <v-row
      justify="center"
      class="ma-5"
    >
      <BookPostKitButtonRegistrationBtn />
      <BookPostKitButtonRegistrationDeleteBtn />
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    selectedBook () {
      return this.$store.state.book.selectedBook
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#Error

```
Cannot read property 'image' of null
```

[image]

I encountered a similar error before, but at that time I got an error not only for image but also for  `title` and  `author`, so this time also with an image only error I don't think

Comment: it's probably an issue with what is in `this.$store.state.book.selectedBook` before `this.$axios.$get(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + this.$route.params.id)` has had a chance to run ... `<img v-if="selectedBook" :src="selectedBook.image">` should fix that

Comment: Few things you should fix: 1. use the `async/await` syntax 2. use `fetch()` (or `asyncData`) 3. use Vuex actions rather than Vuex mutations, as told in the documentation. You should not update the state directly with a mutation since it's sync and here, you're dealing with async things (as most JS is) 4. do not use `v-for`'s index as a `:key` index (it's doing the opposite of what it is supposed to do) 5. your `v-if/v-else` logic will be improved thanks to `fetch()` helper aka `$fetchState.pending` 6. prefer template litterals (with backticks and `$`) rather than string concatenation with `+`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.The error occurs because ``this.$axios. $get (url.POST_API +'posts /'+ this.$route.params.id)`` is executed before the selectedBook.

Comment: Yep, this is how you wrote it. If you make some conditional for it, it should be okay tho, especially with a `computed()`.

Comment: Use ayncData and await to resolve the error. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a question or did you achieve it successfully here?